# Why is my form value empty when it contains a semicolon?

Tags: go, http

The value is empty for `?file=hello;`.

With `?file=hello`, it works.

I tried this:

```golang
err := r.ParseForm()
fmt.Println(err)
fileName := r.FormValue("file")
```

and

```golang
var err error
r.Form, err = url.ParseQuery(r.URL.String())
fmt.Println(err)
fileName = r.FormValue("file")
```

but I get

```
error:invalid semicolon separator in query
```

I expect the forms to contain `map[file:[hello;]]`, but I get `map[]`, both for `PostForm` and `Form`.

Comment: Try to use `url.ParseQuery` which will allow you to handle special characters.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is correct. The [reserved](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) character `;` is not allowed in a [query](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4).

Fix by [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `;` in the query string: `?file=hello%3B`

Answer (score 0):

Using `url.Parse(r.URL.RawQuery)`:

Code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url, err := url.Parse(r.URL.RawQuery)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fileName := r.FormValue("file")
    fmt.Println("Parsed URL:", url)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Parsed URL: %s\nFile from FormValue: %s", url, fileName)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    fmt.Println("Server listening on :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Output:

```
Server listening on :8080
Parsed URL: file=hello;
Parsed URL: file=hello
```